# Activity indicator as annotation accessory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, annotations, mkmapview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a mapView with annotations which they have a button as right accessory view. If you press the button as soon as the annotation details appear then details appear to be empty because there was not enough time to download the required information. What I am seeking is to show an activity indicator as long as there that info is downloading. Here is what I have until now:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

popButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 31, 31)];
[popButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
activityI = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 31, 31)];
[activityI startAnimating];
[popButton addSubview:activityI];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadInfo:) toTarget:self withObject:annotation];
.
.
.
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = popButton;
}

-(void) threadInfo: (MKAnnotationView*) info{

while ([activityI isAnimating]) {
    if (ok ==0) {

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"ok = %i",ok);
        popButton = (UIButton*) info.rightCalloutAccessoryView; <--error*
        popButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        [activityI removeFromSuperview];
        [activityI stopAnimating];
        ok=0;
        }
    }

}
```

where "ok" = integer where 1 = when downloading process completes successfully

where error = Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-["annotation class name" rightCalloutAccessoryView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e7fc60'

even when I comment out the button the activityI still animates without crashes..

Updated: (everything commented out has been tested and not working -not necessarily at the same time. Anything that is not commented was my last try)...

```
-(void) threadInfo: (MKAnnotationView*) annView{
UIButton* popButtons = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 31, 31)];
act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 31, 31)];
[act setColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[act startAnimating];
[popButtons addSubview:act];
while ([act isAnimating]) {
            if (ok ==0) {
        NSLog(@"ok = %i",ok);

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"ok = %i",ok);

      // popButton = (UIButton*) annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView;
//UIButton* popButtons = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 31, 31)];
        popButtons = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
       // UIActivityIndicatorView *currentActivityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[popButton viewWithTag:15];
        //currentActivityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        //[popButtons addSubview:[(UIActivityIndicatorView*) [popButton viewWithTag:15]]];
//            [(UIActivityIndicatorView *) [popButton viewWithTag:15] stopAnimating];
//            [(UIActivityIndicatorView *) [popButton viewWithTag:15] removeFromSuperview];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = popButtons;
        //[popButton addSubview:popButtons];
      //  NSLog(@"view = %@",[popButton viewWithTag:15]);
        //[act stopAnimating];

//            [currentActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
//            [currentActivityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

      //  popButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

    //ok=0;
}
}

}
```

Comment: As I know you are sending the annotion instead of the annView in the method [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadInfo:) toTarget:self withObject:annotation];

Comment: How do you suggest I can fix that? thank you..

Comment: just change the annotation to annView in this method [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadInfo:) toTarget:self withObject:annotation];

Comment: well.. that fixed the crash but the activityI still spins even though the ok==1 and the info button is not showing.. Thank you once more..

Answer (score 0):

The `activityI` you are using in `threadInfo` is not necessarily the one attached to the annotationView that is being used (the `info` variable). It's just the last one that was created by a call to `viewForAnnotation` which can be called at any time for any annotation. you need to get the activity indicator that is on `info`. Here's some pseudo code to start you off. Get the accessoryView, then get the subview that is the activity indicator you added in `viewForAnnotation`

```
popButton = (UIButton*) info.rightCalloutAccessoryView;
UIActivityIndicator *currentActivityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicator *)[popButton **Get the right subview here**];
```

Another option would be to just straight out set the accessoryview to the info button

```
info.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
```

You were pointing popButton to the rightCalloutAccessoryView, then you were pointing it at a new button, but that doesn't change rightCalloutAccessoryView

Comment: as in won't spin or won't go away?

Comment: updated. (everything commented out has been tested and not working -not necessarily at the same time. Anything that is not commented was my last try)... Thank you!

Comment: In its current state you make a `popButtons`, then add `act` to it and start it animating, and while `act` is animating you check is `ok` is 0. Where does `ok` come from? Then you make a new `popButtons` and assign that to the accessoryView. The original `popButtons` is never put on screen as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ohh.. sorry.. I forgot popButtons = (UIButton*) annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView; "ok" is an integer where 1 is assigned to it when the content completes downloading..All i want is for an activity Indicator to show when annotation is selected until the content downloads and when it does, the activity indicator disappears and the lightInfo shows.. How can I fix this?

Comment: How many `ok` variables do you have, just one I assume. And how many annotations do you have? If it is more than one the `ok` variable is useless. You should be checking a value that is associated with this particular annotation. And besides that there is a fundamental flaw in your design. You start a new thread every time the map asks for the annotation view. That can happen at any time, and multiple times. Do you actually intend for the thread to start when the user clicks something, when the annotation is added to the map?

Comment: Yes I only have one "ok". The annotation is added at viewDidAppear || every time the user adds an ann manually by the press of a button. But the callout is shown when the user didSelectAnn.. Then in the ann callout there is a title and subtitle and the right accessory where I wish to replace it with activity indicator while the additional details are being downloaded. And once they do I wish for the activityI to disappear and the light Info to appear.. And yes the thread is created every time the viewForAnn is being called.. I am literally out of options.. Thank you

Comment: You're not out of options, you just need to plan out the logic then the code will follow. First you need to know the state of each annotation and it's download, so you'll need to put a property on each annotation to record if the thing it represents is downloading or finished. When you add the annotation, that's when to start the download and when the that finishes it needs to change that value so that thread needs to have a reference to that annotation. When the mapview wants to draw it it'll check the annotation's property and show or not show an activity indicator according to that.